# Split Java List items within String

Tags: java, string, formatting

The code example below shows a Test class that is supposed to print the list out as follows:

**`'A','B','C'`** (note the quotation marks).

Is there a method I can use to do that kind of formatting directly within the `String` assignment?

```java
public class TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("A");
        test.add("B");
        test.add("C");

        System.out.println(test);

        System.out.println("Expected: 'A','B','C'"); // wanted output

    }
}
```

Output:

```
[A, B, C]
Expected: 'A','B','C'
```

Comment: `test.add("'A'");`

Comment: `test.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"))`

Comment: `System.out.println(String.format("'%s'", String.join("','", test)));`

Comment: @deHaar – If you do not post your comment as an answer, I will do it – and grab the reputation for it! 

Comment: @tquadrat answer posted, let's see what happens ;-)

Comment: @felix You can create a function to print list elements with the format you need using the codes above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option to print the desired result would be to use `String.join` in `System.out.format`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("A");
    test.add("B");
    test.add("C");
    
    System.out.format("'%s'", String.join("','", test));
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
'A','B','C'
```

Applying this format *directly within the `String` assignment* can be done in a similar way, by combining `String.format` and `String.join`:

```java
String formatted = String.format("'%s'", String.join("','", test));
```

Comment: The second option can be *written* shorter: `var formatted = "'%s'".formatted( String.join( "','", test ) );`– The generated code should be the same./And I upvoted your answer! 

Comment: Thanks, @tquadrat, but which Java version is needed for the shorter version?

Comment: `String::formatted` came with Java 15, and `var` came with Java 10. Current version is Java 17 LTS, or Java 18 (or do we have already Java 19? – I use only the LTS versions if possible …)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of a variety of methods to do the conversion.  You can then use your favorite method in a lambda like so.  Here I am using [deHaar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72964947/1552534) solution.

```
Function<List<String>, String> format = lst-> String.format("'%s'", 
                String.join("','", lst));

String result = format.apply(myList);
```

A somewhat more extreme solution is to create a method that returns an `ArrayList` with the `toString` method overridden.  Unless you create a lot of lists of varying types and don't want to have to reformat the list, it is probably overkill.  But it demonstrates a technique.

```
List<String> listString = createList(List.of("A","B","C"));
List<Integer> listInt = createList(List.of(1,2,3,4));
System.out.println(listString);
System.out.println(listInt);
```

prints

```
'A','B','C'
'1','2','3','4'
```

A single no arg method could be used and then the list populated. I added a helper to permit passing a Collection to populate the list upon creation.

- the `no arg` method calls the the other with an empty list.
- the  `single arg` method simply returns an instance of the `ArrayList` with populated with the supplied collection and overriding the `toString()` method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<T> createList() {
    return createList(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
}
    
public static <T> List<T> createList(Collection<T> list) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(list) {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return stream().map(s -> s + "")
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
        }
    };
}
```